# How to Estimate a Multi Channels and Multi Kernels Convolution Kernel (Deep Learning Style) Given the Input and Output Images

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, estimation, deconvolution, deep-learning

**Is it possible that can estimate convolutional kernel that have multi channels and multi filters ?**

I saw answer from this to link to estimate kernel for one channel and one filter ([Estimating Convolution Kernel from Input and Output Images](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/61043/estimating-convolution-kernel-from-input-and-output-images)).
When I tried to implement it, I found that it cannot do correlation because the channel of output is not equal with the channel of input.

For example of data,

Input = 20 x 20 x 3
output = 20 x 20 x 32
kernel size = 3 x 3 x 3 x 32

Comment: so? do it for each output layer individually. -- why are you even trying to do that to the conv2d layer of a neural network? those are usually trained with backprop/gradient descent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible as things are staying linear and spatially invariant.

First, you can basically solve 32 times the same problem of input of size `20x20x3` filtered by `3x3x3` filter with output of size `20x20`.

There are several computational approaches to solve this:

- Build the sparse convolution matrix of the kernel and follow [Estimating Convolution Kernel from Input and Output Images](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/61043).
- Use the operators form and solve this using Conjugate Gradient as in [Automatic Image Enhancement of Images of Scanned Documents (Auto Whitening)](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/50329).
- Use Deep Learning framework and use the [Automatic Differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation) engine to utilize Gradient Descent based solution.